# Invalid synthx error on line 9

Tags: python-2.7

I'm not sure what I did wrong but it's returning invalid syntax on line 9, if anyone can help thank you.

```
hrs = raw_input("Enter Hours:")
rate = raw_input ("Enter Rates:")
hrs = float(hrs)
rate = float(rate)

def computepay(hrs,rate):
    if hrs > 40:
        pay = (hrs * rate) + (rate * 1.5) + (hrs- 40)
        else:
            pay = hrs * rate
return pay


p = computepay(10,20)
print "Pay", p
```

Comment: the `else:` is not indented properly... it should be aligned with the `if`

Comment: Thank you I see my return statement is not indented properly too.